# How to target data attribute with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy library to crawl a webpage.

But I have a problem. I do not know how to target `data` attribute.

I have an link with `data` attribute and `href` as follows:

```
<a data-item-name="detail-page-link" href="this-is-some-link">
```

What I want is the value of `href`. If `a` had class I could do it as follows:

```
response.css('.some-class::attr(href)')
```

But the problem is that I do not know how to target `data-item-name` attribute.

Any advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using scrapy `css` selector, you can do :

```
response.css('a[data-item-name="detail-page-link"]::attr(href)').extract()
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, if you can do this with the `css` method, but with the `xpath` method you should be able to do:

```
response.xpath("//a[@data-item-name]/@href")
```

Comment: how we can do that with beautifulsoup

Comment: Probably this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328746/scraping-data-attribute-with-beautifulsoup