# Scraping data attribute with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning web scraping using BeautifulSoup. The goal is to extract numbers from a financial website for my personal evaluation. So far this is what I've done:

```
import bs4
import requests
r=requests.get('https://www.finnomena.com/stock/CPALL')
r.text
html_page=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Then I was trying to extract numbers at the end of each line (3.69, 3.60, 0.31, and so on) using find/find_all, but didn't know how to refer to those data as I've never seen the elements in this format before:

```
<div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-wrapper sub-topic first-sub-topic">
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">3.69</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">3.60</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">0.31</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">10.26</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">1.58</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">4.73</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">2.64</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">-3.31</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">10.49</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">6.83</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">7.38</div>
    .
    .
    .
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">4.88</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each">-1.40</div>
  <div data-v-30581cd9="" class="data-each"></div>
</div>
```

Try looking into old topics and did some researches already but couldn't find what I want. How can I extract these values?

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 0):

```py
elements = soup.find_all("div", class_="data-each")
text = [i.text for i in elements]
#text is now a list of text data of that div i.e. 3.69, 3.60 ...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer, but I've tried it and print(text). The result shows "[ ]". Not sure what I missed.

Comment: that works fine.. make sure you have loaded the correct data

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4

fh = open('data.html', 'r')
html_page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fh, 'html.parser')

elements = html_page.find_all("div", class_="data-each")

values = list()

for value in elements:
    values.append(value.text)

print(values)
```

I had saved this file as data.html on my laptop. I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: This prints out a list of your required values.

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded from other URL via Ajax. You can get it with `requests`/`json` module:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.finnomena.com/stock/CPALL'
api_url = 'https://www.finnomena.com/fn3/api/stock/financial'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
securityID = soup.select_one('#sec-id').text
data = requests.get(api_url, params={'securityID': securityID}).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data['data']:
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "SecurityID": 4086,
    "Fiscal": 2019,
    "Quarter": 2,
    "Cash": "31370218.00000",
    "DA": "2730218.00000",
    "DebtToEquity": "3.2650",
    "Equity": "83260746.00000",
    "EarningPerShare": "0.51000",
    "EarningPerShareYoY": "2.0000",
    "EarningPerShareQoQ": "-16.3900",
    "GPM": "21.7900",
    "GrossProfit": "31214912.00000",
    "NetProfit": "4794614.00000",
    "NetProfitYoY": "0.3200",
    "NetProfitQoQ": "-16.8900",
    "NPM": "3.3500",
    "Revenue": "143237802.00000",
    "RevenueYoY": "10.4300",
    "RevenueQoQ": "3.1300",
    "ROA": "0.0129",
    "ROE": "0.0553",
    "SGA": "28848813.00000",
    "SGAPerRevenue": "20.1400",
    "TotalDebt": "271842760.00000",
    "DividendYield": "1.40",
    "BookValuePerShare": "10.04",
    "Close": "86.00",
    "MKTCap": "772546715.92800",
    "PriceEarningRatio": "36.30",
    "PriceBookValue": "8.57",
    "EVPerEbitDA": "23.44566",
    "EbitDATTM": "43207107.37300",
    "PaidUpCapital": "8983101.00000",
    "CashCycle": "-39.09884",
    "OperatingActivities": "8059168.00000",
    "InvestingActivities": "-2663473.00000",
    "FinancingActivities": "-9791401.00000",
    "Asset": "369666475.00000"
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look more into json and ajax stuffs for my knowledge.